# Use different parameters when you start the exe than when you start it in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my c# winform app I have to use a file path.
Is it possible that my program automatically uses another path when I’m running the exe then when I’m starting it in visual studio?

Comment: What type of app, Winform?Windows service? etc?

Comment: A WinForm application

Comment: Do you mean setting the path or testing the path? as what is mentioned in the question not mentioning setting the path. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

When starting in Visual studio you send some additional parameters, like the path.

In your project settings:

[image]

For example you could use the parameter to set the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

With WinForm Application: No, should be the same.

The Windows Service Applications, that are installed using `InstallUtil.exe` are located inside `C:\Windows\System32` or `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.

On the other side, the Windows Form applications that are installed using an installer, generally are located in `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. But could be installed somewhere else as choosing the location is provided as an option to the user during the installation process (unless it is restricted to a specific folder)

In all cases, you can get the path by logging the directory location using :

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

Or

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath)
```